# How to remove array values using condition less than and greater than in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove values from using less than and greater than condition for example my array is

```js
[ 138,124,128,126,140,113,102,128,136,110,134,132,130,132,132,104,116,135,120 ]
```

so now my minimum value is 120 and maximum value is 130. I want to remove all the remaining elements from the array. Is this possible in javascript.

I am newbie so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure, just filter the array

```
var arr = [
    138,124,128,126,140,113,102,128,136,110,134,132,130,132,132,104,116,135,120
]

var new_arr = arr.filter(function(x) {
    return x > 120 && x < 130;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yLo6sntm/)

Use `>=` and `<=` to include 120 and 130 as well etc.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use filter, it's created for things like this, the code below should do the job as you want:

```
//ES6
var arr = [138,124,128,126,140,113,102,128,136,110,134,132,130,132,132,104,116,135,120];
var filteredArr = arr.filter(n => n>120 && n<130); //[124, 128, 126, 128]
```

Answer (score 3):

using [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) as below,

```
$.map(a,function(o,i){  if(o < 130 && o > 120) return o; })
```

Comment: 1) there is nothing mentioned about jQuery in the question; 2) you should propose using `$.grep` instead of `$.map` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Just going to extend on the filter and throw it into a reusable function:

```
var arr = [
    138,124,128,126,140,113,102,128,136,110,134,132,130,132,132,104,116,135,120
]
/*
 * @param arr Array of integers
 * @param min Minimum (Inclusive)
 * @param max Maximum (Exclusive)
 */
var filterInRange = function(arr, min, max) {
    return arr.filter(function(item) {
        return item >= min && item < max;
    });
}

console.log(filterInRange(arr, 120, 131).sort()); // [120,124,126,128,128,130]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to return a new array containing only those elements passing a Boolean test.

```
  function isBigEnough(element) { 
    return element >= 10; } 


  var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
```

Returns a new array `[12, 130, 44]`.

Along with [`array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) `array.prototype.filter()` facilitates using a functional programming style in JavaScript.